# oauth on the $.getJson function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck atm of adding an Oauth 2.0 access token on the $.getJSON function

i'm new with javascript, i work on a BI tool, and i need to add an Oauth 2.0 access token to a json get call, the acces token comes from client credential

with Access token URL, CLient ID and Client secret

If the Access token URL is https://test.com:19999/login
Client ID = aaaaaaa
and client secret is bbbbbb

how do i request the token, and add it to the getJson call below?

thanks in advance, i can't find an answer that I understand.

currently I have this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON data to HTML Table using Ajax Jquery getJSON method</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <h1>JSON data To HTML using JSON file </h1>
                <br />
                <table class="table table_bordered table-striped" id=employee_table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var data = {
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "client_id": "KzwgGk8W5yZN2j2MWB4V",
        "client_secret": "g3bXSBkPWPdzRxnjFMwHsk2h"
        };


        // construct an HTTP request
        var getToken= new XMLHttpRequest();
        getToken.open("POST", "https://agiliz.de.looker.com:19999/login", true);
        getToken.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // send the collected data as JSON
        getToken.send(JSON.stringify(data));




        $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",function(data){
            var employee_data = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                employee_data += '<tr>'; 
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>'; 
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.body+'</td>'; 
                employee_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);
        });

    });


</script>
```